# Virtualhost document root access previous folder

Tags: 12.04

How to access previous folder via index.html that not included in virtualhost document root.

For example:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/banking/personal-banking
        ServerName   www.zbux.com
        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/www.zbux.com-error.log
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/www.zbux.com-ssl_access.log combined
        SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/zbux_com.crt
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/zbux_com.ca-bundle
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/zbux.com.key 
</VirtualHost>
```

where personal-banking folder contain index.html and that file need to access folder bak in banking folder.

Comment: Do you mean "parent folder" rather than "previous folder"?

Comment: yes, I means /var/www/banking/

Comment: Make /var/www/banking the DocumentRoot?

Comment: but index file reside under personal-banking

Comment: You could always create a link to it from banking if you can't move it. I guess a relative symbolic link would be best, in case you move your website later.

Comment: OK. I was expecting any other solution. Ultimately I will do that.

Comment: There should never be a directory below the root, seen from within that directory structure. We're talking about the "/" directory. There is no parent.

Answer (score 0):

According to Apache documentation - [**Files Outside the DocumentRoot**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/urlmapping.html#outside):

> There are frequently circumstances where it is necessary to allow web
>   access to parts of the filesystem that are not strictly underneath the
>   DocumentRoot. Apache offers several different ways to accomplish this.
>   On Unix systems, symbolic links can bring other parts of the
>   filesystem under the DocumentRoot. For security reasons, Apache will
>   follow symbolic links only if the **Options** setting for the relevant
>   directory includes **FollowSymLinks** or **SymLinksIfOwnerMatch**.
>
> Alternatively, the **Alias** directive will map any part of the filesystem
>   into the web space. For example, with
>
> ```
>       Alias /docs /var/web
> ```
>
> the URL http://www.example.com/docs/dir/file.html will be served from
>   /var/web/dir/file.html.

So, in your case you could either follow Jo-Erlend Schinstad suggestion and create a simbolic link to "parent file" or try to define Alias directive.

For example you could add:

```
 Alias /file.html /var/www/banking/file.html
 <Directory /var/www/banking>
    Require all granted
 </Directory>
```

A request for `https://www.zbux.com/file.html` would cause the server to return the file `/var/www/banking/file.html`.

Here is [**mod_alias**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) manual.